# Could someone point me to an ember.js project that uses the latest routing system? Bonus points if it uses ember-data as well

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm making my first project with ember.js, and so far haven't been able to find any example projects that use the new routing system.  All the examples from the ember docs use the old routing.

Also, I'd love to see an example of a project that uses Ember Data if anyone knows of one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find an example project using ember 1.0.0 pre.4 here:
https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

There are plans to provide an ember-data version as well. Check here for details:
https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences/pull/9

Another great example can be found here:
https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

Answer (score 3):

Although not free Peepcode just released their "Fire Up Ember.js" which covers the most recent updates to Ember and is probably your best bet for a good introduction.

https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  I actually watched it last night and ran through the tutorial, which was about 85 minutes.  This was by far the most helpful thing I've done so far in learning Ember.  It was $12.  The one drawback is it doesn't go beyond using fixtures for data, but it least it got me started on the front end.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have an ember, ember-data with a rails backend app that I have been working on https://github.com/kiwiupover/cookier updated to use ember 1.0.0 pre.4.

Have a look and let me know what you think.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can check this series of tutorials: http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ember/2013/01/07/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-api-part-1.html. Among other things, it covers new routing system and basics of ember-data.

Additionally, you can take a look at this video introduction to new router from Yehuda Katz: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ed_o3_59ME