# Validating Ember.js architecture

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm struggling to get comfortable with the layout of Ember.js architecture. Could someone please give me hints and tips on the most appropriate way to structure my application.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../script/library/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../script/library/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script src="../script/library/ember.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                Application = Ember.Application.create();

                Application.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
                    templateName: 'application'
                });

                Application.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

                Application.Cat = Ember.Object.extend({
                    name: null,
                    breed: null
                });

                Application.CatView = Ember.View.extend({
                    templateName: 'catCreate'
                });

                Application.CatController = Ember.Controller.extend({
                    content: null,
                    create: function() {
                        alert("controller uploading: " + this.get('content').name);
                    }
                });

                Application.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
                    root: Ember.Route.extend({
                        createCat: Ember.Route.extend({
                            route: '/',
                            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('cat', Application.Cat.create());
                            }
                        })
                    })
                });

                Application.initialize();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
<body lang="en">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="catCreate">
        <h1>Cat Detail</h1>
        {{view Ember.TextField id="name" valueBinding="content.name"}}<br/>
        {{view Ember.TextField id="breed" valueBinding="content.breed"}}<br/>
        <button {{action "create" target="controller"}}>Done</button>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this question: [Could someone point me to an ember.js project that uses the latest routing system? Bonus points if it uses ember-data as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508362/could-someone-point-me-to-an-ember-js-project-that-uses-the-latest-routing-syste) there are some nice app examples.

I personally really like this one:

https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

It gives you a good idea on how to structure your files and use modern tools for development and deployment of your app.